# Script tags interfering with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, head

I'm a newbie to web design and recently got into Bootstrap. I also recently started using Codepen. After working on a project in Codepen I went to copy and paste my code from there into Sublime and for whatever reason it changed some of the stuff on my page i.e. the CSS for my footer and for some of the text.

Now for whatever reason my footer is huge and some of my text is gold. Nowhere in my CSS did I specify gold text. When I move the CSS link in my HTML file below the script tags for Bootstrap my page changes. But regardless of where I put the CSS link or the scripts I still don't get my page displaying the correct way.

Why does the location of my CSS link and my Bootstrap script matter? They are both in the head.

I recently installed Emmet and also recently started toying with Github and pushed the files to Github right before this issue. Not sure if that is relevant.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="realsite/styles.css">

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marcellus+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: always try to put script tags at the bottom of the html page, letting all the page to load quicker and avoid any error

Answer (score 0):

The CSS specification dictates the following rules when applying css:

1. !important
2. Rule origin
3. Specificity
4. Order

It sounds like the 4th is where your getting your issue.  What this means is if you have the following:

```
.cssrule {
    color: white;
}
.cssrule {
    color: gold
}
```

Then the color will be gold, because it was the last rule specified.  Generally, the specificity rule is used to get around this in my experience, so for example:

```
#ida .cssrule {
    color: white;
}
.cssrule {
    color: gold
}
```

in that scenario, a div like this:

```
<div class="cssrule" id="ida">
```

would apply the color white.